# differential forms on covering spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I seem to be under the impression that if $p:A \to B$ is a regular covering (of smooth manifolds) with $\alpha\in \Omega^k(A)$; there exists $b\in \Omega^k(B)$ such that $\alpha= p^*\beta$ if and only if for all $g \in \mathrm{Aut}_B(A)$, $g^*\alpha= \alpha$.

In order to prove this statement, I would like to know what generality it's true in. Is there a version for "irregular" coverings? Fibre bundles?

Comment: This statement is correct for regular coverings. However, it is false for irregular coverings, since the covering group can be trivial but not all the forms project. For principal $G$-bundles it is a bit more subtle, in addition to $G$-invariance you also need a certain vanishing condition. Take a look in Kobayashi-Nomizu's book "Foundations of differential geometry".

Comment: Also, I would look for the term "basic" differential form.